# How close to you does your Familiar have to be for you to be able to dismiss it into its pocket dimension?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

How close to you does your Familiar have to be for you to be able to dismiss it into its pocket dimension?

Within 30', to match the area you can resummon it into?  Within voice range?  Within 100', which is its telepathic communication range?  Within 120' if you use the *Message* cantrip to make the command?  Within any distance on the same plane, if you have *Voice of the Chain Master*?  Within any distance on the same plane, regardless?  Within any distance on any plane, if you cast *Sending* to make the command?  Anywhere in the multiverse?  The *Find Familiar* spell does not say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the range and requirements of a Dismiss action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103278/what-are-the-range-and-requirements-of-a-dismiss-action)

Comment: No, I read that question before I posted this one, and they do not ask the same thing, or have the same answer.  That question was about dismissing magical effects in general, and the answers all were variations on saying that there is no rule for dismissing things in general; it's a case-by-case issue.  So I was asking about this specific case.

Comment: Oh, right. My mistake.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Anywhere

You seem to be operating under the assumption that the "dismissal" of the familiar is a command that it must be given. But the spell does not require the familiar to be communicated with to be dismissed. According to the PHB, p. 239:

> As an action, you can temporarily dismiss your familiar. It disappears
> into a pocket dimension where it awaits your summons. Alternatively,
> you can dismiss it forever.

This is the start of its own paragraph. There is no qualification given for distance, so it can be done at any distance. Contrast this with the qualified other abilities of the familiar, such as needing to be within 100' to cast a spell through it, or within 100' to communicate with it telepathically.

This has been confirmed by [JC on Twitter](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/02/27/can-a-familiar-be-dismissed-if-its-outside-the-100-telepathy-range/).

> Jeremy Crawford: Find familiar puts a range limit on the telepathy it
> provides. It intentionally puts no range limit on dismissing the
> familiar.
>
> "Tobbun": So if you don't know where your familiar is, you can
> just dismiss it and call it forth again near you?
>
> Jeremy Crawford: Yes.

Comment: Not an assumption, but one of the possible ways it might work.  Some of the possibilities I mentioned require a command, and some do not.  So that was part of the question -- which of these is the limit, if any?

Comment: Good point! I missed the “within any distance on the same plane regardless” option.