# Does a Wall of Force block concentration on a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration, wall

If a spell was cast on a recipient prior to the [*wall of force*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force) being brought into existence, and that recipient was then on the other side of the wall from the caster, does *wall of force* prevent concentration from being maintained on the other spell?

Comment: It may be better to ask about specific interactions between specific spells. Haven't downvoted, but is there a specific scenario where you encountered this problem? Is this actually about Line of Effect and Line of Sight?

Comment: It's not about Line of Sight, as the Wall is invisible...it *may* be about Line of Effect, if Line of Effect is required for maintaining concentration on a spell.

Comment: The spells that made me even think of asking this were Shield of Faith, and Urchin's Spines (a homebrew spell from Codex of waves), both of which may be cast on another person and require concentration to maintain.

Comment: It may be better, then, to ask if concentration is broken by a break in LoE if Wall of Force breaks LoE.

Comment: Is there anything in the books that makes you believe this would be the case? Please edit all relevant info into the question :)

Comment: Related: [Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59734/can-spells-be-cast-through-a-wall-of-force)

Answer (score 6):

## No

Unless there is a reason a caster's concentration should fail (failed a saving throw from taking damage, incapacitated, etc.) the caster can continue to concentrate up to the end of the duration of the spell.

Nothing in concentration requires maintaining line of sight or line of effect, so the Wall of Force is irrelevant from the perspective of the caster keeping his concentration.

Comment: Or even [staying in range](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60586/does-going-outside-of-range-or-line-of-sight-after-casting-a-spell-have-any-effe).

Answer (score 1):

## No.

The PHB / [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime) defines what can end concentration. And a Wall of Force does not cause these.

> Casting another spell that requires concentration.
> Taking damage.
> Being incapacitated or killed.

However it also then continues to say

> The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you're on a storm-tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell.

So if the DM decides that the Wall of Force might somehow break the caster's concentration, a Constitution saving throw may be required.

Comment: I made an edit on your post, see this [meta Q&A](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/use-real-headers-instead-of-fake-headers) for why. tl;dr don't use bold for headers, use header formatting for headers.